# how to add comment to existing view in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to ask you how add comment to view ( not table ) in MySQL. I tried something like this:

```
ALTER VIEW VIEWNAME COMMENT comment
```

but this not working.

Comment: Is there any other good way how to add description to view and save him with this view in database? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to script the entire view, add the column to your query, and execute the change.  You can't just add a field to the view like you would a table because it doesn't know where it should come from.